# How to run a function asynchronously (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I am loading data from an api and I need to run a function once the code is loaded.

```
function make(query, callback){
    console.log("1");
    var results = makeRequest(query);
    return callback(results);
};

setPoints = function(results){
    console.log("2");
    for(var key in results)
    {
        console.log("3");
        var myLatLng = {lat: key.lat, lng: key.lon};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    }
};

make(3, setPoints);

makeRequest = function(place) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', "https://trailapi-trailapi.p.mashape.com/?limit=25&q[city_cont]=San+Luis+Obispo&radius=205", true);
    req.setRequestHeader('X-Mashape-Key', 'JwTKoEqkTbmsh3eqT0fBweCHYIAUp1h1GCbjsnkh59Bok0iqOC');
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState === 4) {
            if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                var latLongs = response.places.map(function (key) {
                    return {lat: key.lat, lon: key.lon};
                });
                console.log("Returned");
                return latLongs;
            } else {
                alert("Failed to load " + req.status);
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```

I would like for the code to log "1, returned, 2, 3". Instead it is logging "1, 2, returned".

Comment: I mean, you could wrap it in a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) call. It seems a little strange that you're intentionally doing that though.

Comment: You need to pass that callback as an argument to `makeRequest` (which is the actually asynchronous function), where you'd call it from the `readystatechange` callback *instead* of `return`ing the result.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is pass the callback to the function `makeRequest`. This callback is running after `XMLHttpRequest` is completed.

```
function make(query, callback){
    console.log("1");
    makeRequest(query,callback);

};

setPoints = function(results){
    console.log("2");
    for(var key in results)
    {
        console.log("3");
        var myLatLng = {lat: key.lat, lng: key.lon};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    }
};

make(3, setPoints);
makeRequest = function(place, callback) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', "https://trailapi-trailapi.p.mashape.com/?limit=25&q[city_cont]=San+Luis+Obispo&radius=205", true);
    req.setRequestHeader('X-Mashape-Key', 'JwTKoEqkTbmsh3eqT0fBweCHYIAUp1h1GCbjsnkh59Bok0iqOC');
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState === 4) {
            if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                var latLongs = response.places.map(function (key) {
                    return {lat: key.lat, lon: key.lon};
                });
                console.log("Returned");
                return callback(latLongs);
            } else {
                alert("Failed to load " + req.status);
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```

Another **horrible solution** in your problem is to do the function `makeRequest` synchronous.

In the method `XMLHttpRequest.open` you define the AJAX a/synchronous function in the third parameter (only should change the value `true` to `false`).

```
makeRequest = function(place) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', "https://trailapi-trailapi.p.mashape.com/?limit=25&q[city_cont]=San+Luis+Obispo&radius=205", false);
    req.setRequestHeader('X-Mashape-Key', 'JwTKoEqkTbmsh3eqT0fBweCHYIAUp1h1GCbjsnkh59Bok0iqOC');
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState === 4) {
            if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                var latLongs = response.places.map(function (key) {
                    return {lat: key.lat, lon: key.lon};
                });
                console.log("Returned");
                return latLongs;
            } else {
                alert("Failed to load " + req.status);
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```

Comment: A simple, and simply horrible solution.

Comment: Yes, its is horrible solution, but in his problem obtained the result expected. Would you explain different between callback and end the function or synchronous function. Thanks :).

Comment: OP is already trying to use callbacks, he only missed one step. This solution is just inappropriate.

Comment: I understand now, I will edit the alternative solution. Thanks